# String contains any character in group?

Tags: python

I have a set of characters: \,/,?,% etc.
I also have a string, lets say "This is my string % my string ?"

I want to check if any of the characters are present in the string.

This is not to check for a substring, but to check for a character in a set.

I could do this:

```
my_str.find( "/" ) or my_str.find( "\\" ) or my_str.find( "?" )
```

but it's very ugly and inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) here.

```
>>> string = r"/\?%"
>>> test = "This is my string % my string ?"
>>> any(elem in test for elem in string)
True
>>> test2 = "Just a test string"
>>> any(elem in test2 for elem in string)
False
```

Comment: Getting an error. Here's my string: invalid_chars = "/\\?%*:|"<>\. " And the error is "unexpected character after line continuation character". Using the set from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Comment: The formatting of your string is wrong. Use `r'/\?%*:|"<>. '`. I believe it has all the characters you want.

Comment: Assuming the characters from the (smaller) permanent set ("string") are all ever remotely likely to be seen, then you got it backwards, and it should be `any(elem in string for elem in test)` rather than the other way around. As you have it, you'll exhaust the entire (longer) input value looking for only the first character in the set before proceeding to the next, and so on. The code snippet I just gave checks *all* of the candidates for each character in the input, before proceeding to the next. This allows for early abandonment more often, assuming the targets are all somewhat likely.

Comment: Because this approach relies on `elem in test` - where both are strings - it does a substring search. This can be slower, but it is more flexible. `for elem in string` can, instead of drawing the elements as individual symbols from a source string, take strings from a list (or other iterable).

Answer (score 9):

I think Sukrit probably gave the most pythonic answer.  But you can also solve this with set operations:

```
>>> test_characters = frozenset(r"/\?%")
>>> test = "This is my string % my string ?"
>>> bool(set(test) & test_characters)
True
>>> test2 = "Just a test string"
>>> bool(set(test2) & test_characters)
False
```

Comment: In a logical context, such as an `if` statement, the `bool()` call is unnecessary. i.e. `if set(test2) & test_characters:`. Also `test_characters` doesn't need to be a frozen.

Comment: The top-voted answer can also work with `string` replaced by a list of substrings to look for. The `set` based approach can only look for single characters (strictly speaking, Unicode code points) because it is no longer using the `in` operator on strings (which does a substring search, unlike for lists where it tests for a single element).

Answer (score 5):

Use regex!

```
import re

def check_existence(text):
    return bool(re.search(r'[\\/?%]', text))

text1 = "This is my string % my string ?"
text2 = "This is my string my string"

print check_existence(text1)
print check_existence(text2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: RE = re.compile('[\\\/\?%]')
In [3]: RE.search('abc')

In [4]: RE.search('abc?')
Out[4]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1081bc1d0>
In [5]: RE.search('\\/asd')
Out[5]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1081bc3d8>
```

`None` indicates non characters in the set are present in the target string.

Answer (score 1):

And of course the most non-Pythonic way, but at least to me more readable.

Define the function:

```
def containsSpecialCharacters(self, string: str, test: str) -> bool:
    for special in string:
        if special in test:
            return True
    return False
```

This call:

```
string = r"/\?%"
test = "This is my string % my string ?"
print(self.containsSpecialCharacters(string, test))
```

returns *True*

This call

```
test2 = "Just a test string" 
print(self.containsSpecialCharacters(string, test2))
```

returns *False*