# extract from file and index

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, extract, sentence

i want extract the sentences witch contain any defined punctuation

1. i can not increase the punctuation is only one but i need any time i am increasing it gives me error

2.example :

lookup=',' but i want put more inside lookup like(?!@,.)

```
lookup = ','
with open('testing_for_tools.txt') as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if lookup in line:
            print('found at line:', num)
            print(line)
```

output is correct for only one , :

```
found at line: 1
i went to city center, and i bought xbox5 , and some other stuff

found at line: 6
i have to go home, then sleep  ؟
```

Comment: Please include the code that was actually yielding the error. It seems you have only included your "successful" code, which is not very helpful for debugging as it is already seemingly correct

Comment: look i modified my code now it is working with only (,) only i need make it like (,.@!?)

Comment: your check is: `if lookup in line`.  If `lookup=',.@!?'`, you will only find lines that actually contain `',.@!?'` in its entirety.  If you want to check if the line contains *any* of those characters, that is a different check. See this question for how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463556/string-contains-any-character-in-group

Comment: i know but if when i make lookup=',.@?!' now the program will only print those sentences that contain all lookup while i want if any thing in look up find anywhere in file print the sentence and the number of line

Comment: Yes I understand. Please read my comment again and the linked question, it covers this exact problem

Comment: i do not want to remove it i just want to print the line number and sentences

Comment: thanks i made `lookup = r",?@!"` but now it prints nothing any idea?

Comment: You may have missed the main point of the answer in that question. The `r"string"` isn't really the essential part of the answer, it is suggesting that instead of checking `string in test` you should check `any(elem in test for elem in string)`. That is the part you should apply to your code