# How do i put "denied" characters in the same line?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
username=input("input username= ")
if "?" in username:
    print("the following characters are         allowed: a-z, -, num's")
    quit()
if "!" in username:
    print("only a-z, -, and num's are                 allowed")
    quit()
else:
    print("hello", username)
```

I want to simplify the code by putting all of the "denied" characters (here, `?` and `!`) in the same line of code. How can I make the code work like that. I have tried using `or` and `elif`, but couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: Why is this tagged `android`?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463556/string-contains-any-character-in-group

Comment: @ScottHunter i tagged it as android because i use android, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @ivvija i'll try it, be right back

Comment: @ivvija i looked at the thread but i i don't really know how to implement and modify them to find a specific item

Comment: " tagged it as android because i use android" Please don't do this. Tags are for identifying *what people need to know in order to answer the question properly*. Use the `android` tag only if the code uses Android-specific libraries, or if there is some other reason why an Android expert would have a special advantage in answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the characters you want ignored in a list then use python's 'any' statment to check if any of the characters to be denied are found in username as follows :

```py
username=input("input username= ")

# put unwanted chars here
to_deny = ['?', '!']

if any([char in username for char in to_deny]):
    print("only a-z, -, and num's are allowed")
    quit()
else:
    print("hello", username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use set arithemtic to detect if string contain at least one of denied characters as follows

```
username=input("input username= ")
denied = {"?","!"}
if denied.intersection(username):
    print("username contain denied character or character, denied are:",*denied)
else:
    print("hello", username)
```